# Order Break Between Model And Main Forms c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two forms  form1 is main form and form two is model form I want to set the forms as below:

Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this);

}
```

The above would set the form1 owner of form2 and form2 would be shown but the problem is that this will break the order of forms on press of Alt+Tab keys hence I have tried it with another way as below.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(this);

 }
```

This would be works but the problem is that the dialogue forms will not allow me to maximise/minimise and close

My form2 is borderless form and it is set to show on specific location as to fit with main form1. My aim to do not shows the form2 in Alt+Tab list and as I close the form2 then form1 will show immediately without break order of form.

When I press Alt+Tab keys on first condition and try to close form2 then the other application shown instead of form1 which is I do not want.

Is there any solution of this problem?.

Comment: Why not make `Form2` a user control instead of a form?

Comment: @Bobson, So did you mean that user control is diferent from win forms as it would ultimately derived from the forms.

Comment: If you inherit from `UserControl` instead of `Form`, you can place the form2 inside form1 in the same way you would add a new button or textbox.

Comment: @Bobson, That I know but I mean that by inherit the win forms it would not change the matters of show() and showdialouge() method it would give same feature as it is the form has.

Comment: ... as the same is derived from the win forms.

Comment: No, you wouldn't have `.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()`.  Instead, you'd have `.Visible = true`.

Comment: @Bobson, Ok then what about close of UserControl.If you close the UserControl then it will also close the main form and which I don't want.

Comment: There's no way to close the UserControl, just as there's no way to close a button.  You can only close the form it's on, or set the control to `.Visible = false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really sounds like you could do the second form as a custom control.

See [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/649xahhe.aspx) and [this set of examples](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html).

Think of it as a standard control, like a `Button`, `DataGridView`, `TextBox`, or the like, except that you have total control over it.  You can show or hide it, you don't have to worry about where it is positioned, it won't take focus away from the parent form, and so on.  And you can put whatever other controls you want in it, encapsulate all their logic, etc.

Comment: your post is useful but one confusion on my mind and that is if I have usercontrol more than 50 then how to maintain it on winapplication form1. If so then I have to drag and drop 50 usercontrol on form1 and which is very complicate to work between winapplication code and usercontrol forms by setting visible property to true or false

Comment: @MaheshWagh - wouldn't you have the same issue with needing to create 50 variants of form2?

Comment: No it's not about 50 variants of form2 there are about more then 50 separate forms which are container of controls. No need to add on main forms where as here in usercontrol case you have to add it to main forms like controls textbox and datagridview.

Comment: I am appreciate your idea but I am confuse about to handle the 50 usercontrol or more then 50. Is there specific method or idea to handle it?.

Comment: @MaheshWagh - I'm still somewhat confused. Are you saying that you have 50+ forms which would need this control on it?  Or you would need 50+ instances of this control on the one form?  Or that there are 50+ things inside the control?

Comment: @MaheshWagh - Also, check out the second example from [this page](http://sharpertutorials.com/creating-custom-controls-windows-forms/) (the one called "User Controls").  Does that clarify things at all?

Answer (score -1):

A possible hack is to keep your parent form active after opening child form as a modal form, so that you could do maximize/minimize your parent as well. An extension method:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool enable);
public static DialogResult ShowDialogSpecial(this Form formToBeShown, Form parent)
{
    parent.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => EnableWindow(parent.Handle, true)));
    formToBeShown.ShowDialog(parent);

    return formToBeShown.DialogResult;
}
```

You can call:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    //additionally do f2.ShowInTaskbar = false to make sense.
    f2.ShowDialogSpecial(this);
}
```

This wont let child form truly act as non-modal form, since child form can cover over parent form.

Comment: @MaheshWagh yes it works, but its not an ideal way. I recommend against it.